# Blocking read from file in PHP

Tags: php, blocking, synchronous

Here is what I want expressed in bash:

```
while true; do
  while read $line; do
    echo "Heard: $line"
  done < fifo
done
```

Here, fifo is the path to a named pipe. This will read from the fifo, but if the fifo is empty, it will block until there is something in it.

Trying a similar thing in PHP results in a busy-loop since fgets returns when there is nothing in the pipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[fopen() is where you get blocking](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php#41243); not on fgets(). My problem was that I fopen()ed the file then started my loop, so once the pipe was written to once, the busy loop would start. Instead, putting the fopen() in the loop makes it block until there is a writer.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
sleep(1);
```

to avoid heavy cpu usage. This is just the most simple way to avoid busy-loops. You can also look at [stream_select()](http://php.net/stream-select), which allows to specify a timeout how long the script should wait for a readable (or writeable) stream. Or you can try to change the default behaviour of [fgets()](http://php.net/fgets) for a specific stream with [stream_set_blocking()](http://php.net/stream-set-blocking). I dont know exactly (I didnt try it myself), but it seems the last one is the one you are looking for.

```
stream_set_blocking($stream, 1);
$r = fgets($stream);
```

Comment: I saw stream_set_blocking, but in order to create a stream from a file, it first reads the whole file then wraps the contents in a stream wrapper. This won't accomplish what I need.

Comment: You have not provided any code, but you mentioned fifo-pipes, so I assumed you really use [posix_mkfifo()](http://php.net/posix-mkfifo). As you can see at the example on the manual page they are useable with *stream_select()*

Answer (score 1):

I believe [fread](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) is blocking.